# source .bashrc in a script not working

Tags: bash, command-line

I am doing a script that is installing ros and after installing it, compiling a workspace with catkin_make.

I found the solution to solve my problem but I can't explain the reason. I have a file called install.bash that is calling others:

```
#!/bin/bash

source 01_install_ros.bash
```

What is important is in `01_install_ros.bash`:

```
# variable not set because it is done in the script setup.bash of ros
echo "before source in 01_install_ros"
echo "ROS_ROOT: "$ROS_ROOT
whereis catkin_make
echo ""

echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> $HOME/.bashrc
# doesn't set the variables
source "$HOME"/.bashrc
# the solutions
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash

# variables not set if I use the source of .bashrc
echo "after source in 01_install_ros"
echo "ROS_ROOT: "$ROS_ROOT
whereis catkin_make
echo ""
```

As written in comments, sourcing .bashrc instead of directly setup.bash doesn't work. I really don't get why. Can you explain me?

Comment: `.bashrc` is intended to be read by the Bash itself. Why do you think it might be necessary to do it in a script?

Comment: Because I add a line at the end in `01_install_ros.bash` that is sourcing setup.bash from ros. And I need to source it.

Comment: Because I add the line `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" at the end of `.bashrc`. I do that in `01_install_ros.bash`. And I need to source this setup.bash to have access to catkin_make in $PATH. What I don't understand is why I don't have this access when I am sourcing .bashrc. I hope to be clear.

Comment: Use `exec bash` to start a new Bash, which has read the updated `.bashrc`.

Comment: I think that you don't get it. I don't search for a solution. I want an explanation. Why it doesn't work with `source ~/.bashrc`? I know how to solve it: `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` directly.

Comment: Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or use `set -x` to find out yourself.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, copy paste the code that I put, and if you have ros installed, it will reproduce the thing...

Comment: It's possible that `$HOME` is not set in whatever environment you're invoking it. You should do `set -e` at the start to make sure it stops at the first failure. It might reveal more.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Some platforms come with a `~/.bashrc` that has a conditional at the top that explicitly stops processing if the shell is found to be *non-interactive*** - even though `bash` only automatically sources `~/.bashrc` in *interactive* (non-login) sessions anyway.

For example, on Ubuntu 18.04:

```sh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
    *) return;;
esac
```

A similar test, seen in `/etc/bash.bashrc` on the same platform:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

If this is the case, **sourcing `~/.bashrc` from a *script* will have no effect,** because scripts run in *non-interactive* shells by default.

Your **options** are:

- Either: **deactivate the conditional** in `~/.bashrc`
- Or: Try to to **emulate an interactive shell** before invoking `source ~/.bashrc`.
  The specific emulation needed depends on the specifics of the conditional, but there are two likely approaches; you may have to employ them *both* if you don't know ahead of time which conditional you'll encounter:

  - `set -i` temporarily to make `$-` contain `i`, indicating an interactive shell.
  - If you know the contents of the line that performs the interactivity test, filter it out of the `~/.bashrc` using `grep`, and then source the result with `eval` (the latter should generally be avoided, but it in this case effectively provides the same functionality as sourcing).
    Note that making sure that environment variable `PS1` has a value is *not* enough, because Bash *actively resets it* in non-interactive shells - see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/462678/54804) for background information.

    - `eval "$(grep -vFx '[ -z "$PS1" ] && return' ~/.bashrc)"`

Alternatively, **if you control how your own script is invoked**, you can invoke it with 
`bash -i script`.

Comment: `set -i` doesn't seem to work, and I can't modify `$-` manually either.

Comment: Are there any downsides deactivating the conditional?

Comment: @deanresin: I don't think so, given that `bash` only sources `~/.bashrc` automatically in _interactive_ (non-login) sessions anyway.

Comment: @nupanick, the answers states that `set -i` only works if `~/.bashrc` contains the conditional listed first in the answer, where the (read-only) `$_` variable is checked. If the conditional is based on `$PS1` or similar, you must use the `grep`-based technique.