# source bashrc doesn't work in cron

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

All we know that cron ignores variables defined in “.bashrc” and “.bash_profile”, so we have to define it inside cron. I constantly do the same what was written inside the similar question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67940/cron-ignores-variables-defined-in-bashrc-and-bash-profile but still global variables inside .bashrc still not working. I found way to execute it - by defining sh script with "set +a" bashrc script. But "source" still doesn't work.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
BASH_ENV=/root/.bashrc
PATH=:/opt/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
MAILTO=root HOME=/

# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /bin/bash -c 'source $HOME/.bashrc; echo "SPARK_HOME: '$SPARK_HOME'"; echo "JAVA_HOME: '$JAVA_HOME'"' > /var/log/file.log 2>&1

# DO NOT DELETE LAST LINE
```

return log file

```
SPARK_HOME: /opt/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
JAVA_HOME:
```

also tried to execute this in interactive mode as it was written by mklement0
[source .bashrc in a script not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43659084/source-bashrc-in-a-script-not-working)

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -i source /root/.bashrc; echo $JAVA_HOME > /var/log/file.log 2>&1
```

As you can see SPARK_HOME is defined inside crontab whilst JAVA_HOME only in .bashrc. P.S in bashrc java home is defined "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_131"
All different cron jobs work fine when I change JAVA_HOME to SPARK_HOME, tried different crontab jobs but the answer is the same as it was.

ubuntu kernel version is

```
uname -a
Linux 6101c32b9243 4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 16 05:37:08 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 7):

Your last attempt runs `bash` and sources the file, then exits Bash and runs the `echo` in the calling shell, which isn't Bash, and of course doesn't know or care that the now-defunct Bash process loaded some settings and then forgot them when it exited. (Or, well, this is what would happen if you fixed the simple quoting errors to keep the `source` command and its argument as a single string.)

The superficial fix is easy;

```
* * * * * bash -c 'source $HOME/.bashrc; echo "$JAVA_HOME"' >/var/log/file.log 2>&1
```

The *proper* fix, however, is probably to encapsulate all of this in a separate script and keep your `crontab` really simple.

(Are you really sure your user is allowed to overwrite the log file? Replacing the log once a minute seems rather misdirected, although it's good enough for a quick test to see if the job is running at all.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've tried what you have written and still it only works with $SPARK_HOME variable. anything else that I can try ?) it's already even doesn't funny. P.S the overwriting log is just for testing.

Comment: If you have two jobs writing to the same file, it will obviously look like only one of them is working. But again, putting all your commands in a script file is probably the way to go, and removes this sort of problem.

Comment: I have only 1 job.

Comment: Your post clearly shows two `cron` jobs writing to the same file, pretty much simultaneously. If that's not correct then I really suggest you review the [troubleshooting help in the Stack Overflow `cron` tag info page](/tags/cron/info) and maybe then if you still can't figure it out, post a new question with more details about what *exactly* you are doing and how *exactly* you conclude that only one variable can be printed but not the other.

Comment: As repeatedly suggested already, putting `echo "SPARK_HOME: '$SPARK_HOME'"; echo "JAVA_HOME: '$JAVA_HOME'"` in a single script and demonstrating that one is printed while the other is not when you run this script out of `cron` would be a nice demo. Log entries showing when exactly `cron` ran what exactly should also be useful for diagnostics.

Comment: Have done what you said. can see tre reply. ps only 1 job is existing. Maybe there is something with bash interactive mode?

Comment: So it sources both variables but prints only one? If that is indeed the case, I really think a separate, new question is required. Again, the `cron` tag info page I linked above should suggest a number of relevant diagnostics to include.